# How to use a Vue VM variable in a component?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

I have the following working code which displays elements of an array defined in Vue:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="number in numbers">{{number}}</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

I now want to move the inner `div` into a `template`. The code below is what I thought would be working:

```js
Vue.component(
  'numbers', {
    template: "#templ"
  }
)

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <numbers></numbers>
</div>

<template id="templ">
  <div v-for="number in numbers">{{number}}</div>
</template>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
```

This raises in the console

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "numbers" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.  (found in component < numbers >)

**Does this mean that `vm.numbers` is not available in the component?** How should I access this data for the `v-for` and mustache expression?

I suspected that I should use `props`:

```
Vue.component(
    'numbers',
    {
        template: "#templ",
        props: ['numbers']
    }
)
```

and modified accordingly the HTML:

```
<numbers numbers="numbers"></numbers>
```

but this method passes the string "numbers" instead of `vm.numbers`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your template as follows:

```
<numbers :numbers="numbers"></numbers>
```

which is a short-hand syntax for:

```
<numbers v-bind:numbers="numbers"></numbers>
```

This ensures that the `numbers` object is passed as `props` instead of the string "numbers"

Comment: You can also install [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to find out what props / data objects are available under various components. It is very helpful during development.